# return folders from url

Tags: javascript, jquery

I  am looking to write a piece of javascript that will do the following:

Look at current url and return any folders in the url ie:

http://localhost/folder1/page.aspx returns -> /folder1/

http://localhost/page.aspx returns -> /

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
window.location.pathname.substr(0, window.location.pathname.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try     `window.location.pathname` to get its path. [for ref](http://docs.sun.com/source/816-6408-10/location.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Via `window.location` you can access the full URL of your running script. Then you can use a REGEX to extract the part you want, in this case the path.

Answer (score 0):

The [`location`](http://www.w3.org/TR/Window/#location) property (on `window`) ([link](http://www.w3.org/TR/Window/#location)) has a variety of properties that you can use to get that information.

[Here's an example](http://jsbin.com/emumu5) of what's available:

```
var loc, name, value;

loc = window.location;
for (name in window.location) {
  value = loc[name];
  if (typeof value != 'function') {
    display(name + ": " + value);
  }
}

function display(msg) {
  var p = document.createElement('p');
  p.innerHTML = msg;
  document.body.appendChild(p);
}
```